# R/RStudio Check If A Function Call Has 2 Definitions From Packages

Tags: r, function, scoping

This may be more of an RStudio question, but is there a way to check if a particular function call has more than 1 definition and break if it does in R?

For example, let's say I had the `stats` and `dplyr` packages loaded and I was using the `filter` function. Is there a setting to have the code break of there are two instances of `filter` loaded, as would be the case?

I know that I can simply do `stats::filter` to scope to the stats version of filter, but I'd like a way to automatically warn me if there's a disambiguation to be done and I would scope after the fact.

Thanks,

Comment: The `conflicts()` command shows all "shadowed" functions. But there's nothing in R that can check for this at run time for a specific function call as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Nice, I could see this being helpful.

Comment: No, this is not more of an RStudio question. Its plain ol R.

Comment: @Spacedman I added that alluding to the possibility there was a setting in RStudio to check this.

Answer (score 3):

Just pay attention when you call `library(...)` as base R does this for you (and always has).

```
R> library(stats)
R> library(dplyr)

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

R>
```

Comment: That is true. Is there a way I could possibly capture this warning? It's not always easy and a little inconvenient when loading many packages.

Comment: You sort of learn by doing which packages have this problem. The one I used here as an illustration, and which your question references, is somewhat notorious for the issue.  In practice, if you care about reproducibility you can simply not use it, or at least never load it via `library()`.  Or never use base R ...

Comment: After that, it is really a matter of 'walking' your library and all its (exported) functions to try to find clashes -- and `conflicts()` probably helps.

Comment: It definitely does. Put together a "solution" below that makes this much easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programmatically check for any possible collision with all loaded packages, you could:

Use `search()` to get a list all attached packages (using my currently open project).

```
search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:bindrcpp" 
 [3] "package:lubridate" "package:ggplot2"  
 [5] "package:dplyr"     "tools:rstudio"    
 [7] "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
 [9] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
[11] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
[13] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Iterate over the list of packages, and use `lsf.str()` to get a list of functions:

```
> x <- as.list(lsf.str("package:dplyr"))
> length(x)
[1] 231
> x[2]
[[1]]
[1] "add_count"
```

Combine all the lists and check for duplicates using `duplicated()`:

```
duplicated(c(1,1))
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

**EDIT**

As someone else pointed out, `conflicts()` does this all for you already. [Documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/conflicts)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. I did some digging and with using your suggestions and the package `NCmisc` that has a function called `list.functions.in.file`, I can detect on source, what functions are potentially a scoping issue.

Code to check would be in your file and would be something like this:

```
require(NCmisc)
funcNames <- sort(unlist(list.functions.in.file(scriptSelfReference)))
cf <- conflicts()
if (any(cf %in% funcNames)) { warning(paste0("The following functions in your file are potential conflicts and should be scoped: ", paste0(cf[cf %in% funcNames], collapse = ", "), "."))}
```

Hope this helps someone, helped me!